# How do I use JQuery or JavaScript to remove all links in a table?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table that I would like to export to Excel but I don't want any of the hyperlinks to come through. Is that possible?

I noticed that something similar was being done in the thread 
[JQuery remove images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6098958/jquery-remove-images) but I don't thing it quite the same as what I need?

I would also like to keep the text within the  tag if possible?

Example:

```
<table class="surveyTable" id="Summary">
    <tr>
        <th>Section</th>
        <th title="3584">
            <a href="test.php?id=3584">
                Call 1
            </a>
        </th> ...
```

I would like to have the ability to export the above without the href yet retaining the "Call 1" but maybe this is not possible?

Thanks!

Comment: What text do you want to keep? Within which one?

Comment: Thank you everyone, very quick responses! debianek, The txt I wanted to keep was Call 1. I have the answer now but thank you for asking.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2556051/remove-links-with-javascript

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, that should be fairly simple, using the function callback signature of `replaceWith`:

```
$('#summary a').replaceWith(function() {
    return this.childNodes;
});
```

That removes each `a` element and replaces each one with all of its child nodes.  This means that you keep any formatting.

If you wanted to just have plain text, that would also be easy to achieve:

```
$('#summary a').replaceWith(function() {
    return $.text([this]);
});
```

Comment: OP didnt ask for that, but *if you just want to remove those links* just do . . . .. . . .. . ..  `$('#yourCssSelector a').remove();` ;)

Answer (score 7):

You can do this easily with the following code and jQuery will handle looping through all `a` and replace those with the text within.

```
 $('#Summary a').contents().unwrap();
```

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/joycse06/szKQv/1/)

[$.unwrap()](http://api.jquery.com/unwrap/)

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
$('th a').each(function(){
   $(this).replaceWith($(this).text())
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested for syntax correctness, but, something along these lines should work:

```
$('#Summary a').each( function() {
   $(this).parent().html($(this).html());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#Summary").find('a').each(function(){
  $(this).attr('href','#');
});
```

I believe this will solve your purpose.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.surveyTable tr th a, .surveyTable tr td a').each(function(){
   $(this).replaceWith($(this).text());
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qTB8E/3/